# How to implement the data structure for "transferring ownership" of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

I am using rails to build an application where an owner owns many products. And each product can be transferred to another owner when needed.

At my first thought I imagine a simple relationship

`Owner has_many :products
product belongs_to owner`

As I need to add a many_to_many relationship, I thought may be I can add a `owners_products_table`. However I will not be able to distinguish the period of when each owner owns the product.

I thought have adding columns like `start_owning_at`, and `end_owning_at` ..but it seems to make all the query process very troublesome..

I wonder how I can implement the transfer ownership data relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to keep track of the period for which each user owns a product? I think your instinct about how to model it is correct, and you can work on making the queries simple and intuitive.

I would model this like so:

```
Owner 
  has_many :product_ownerships
  has_many :products, :through => :product_ownerships

Product 
  has_many :product_ownerships
  has_many :owners, :through => :product_ownerships
  #some named scopes for convenience
  scope :at_time, ->(time) { where("product_ownerships.ownership_starts_at <= ? and product_ownerships.ownership_ends_at => ?", time, time)} 
  scope :current, -> { at_time(Time.now) }  

ProductOwnership
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :product
  #fields: product_id, owner_id, ownership_starts_at, ownership_ends_at
  #some named scopes for convenience
  scope :at_time, ->(time) { where("product_ownerships.ownership_starts_at <= ? and product_ownerships.ownership_ends_at => ?", time, time)} 
  scope :current, -> { at_time(Time.now) }
```

Now you should be able to say things like

```
  @owner = Owner.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @products = @owner.products.current
  #or 
  @products = @owner.products.at_time(Time.parse(params[:time]))
```

etc, or do the same to list product_ownerships rather than products: this is useful if you have a form page where the user can update the times of the product_ownerships, for example.

EDIT - btw, in this schema, when a new Owner takes a product, you should make a new ProductOwnership, and set the `ownership_ends_at` field for the old owner to be the handover time.